# pandas DataFrame re-order cells for each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, position

I have a dataframe of groups of 3s like:

```
group   value1   value2   value3
1       A1       A2       A3
1       B1       B2       B3
1       C1       C2       C3
2       D1       D2       D3
2       E1       E2       E3
2       F1       F2       F3
...
```

I'd like to re-order the cells within each group according to a fixed rule by their 'positions', and repeat the same operation over all groups.

This 'fixed' rule will work like below:

Input:

```
group   value1       value2       value3
1       position1    position2    position3
1       position4    position5    position6
1       position7    position8    position9
```

Output:

```
group   value1       value2       value3
1       position1    position8    position6
1       position4    position2    position9
1       position7    position5    position3
```

Eventually the dataframe should look like (if this makes sense):

```
group   value1   value2   value3
1       A1       C2       B3
1       B1       A2       C3
1       C1       B2       A3
2       D1       F2       E3
2       E1       D2       F3
2       F1       E2       D3
...
```

I know how to re-order them if the dataframe only has one group - basically create a temporary variable to store values, get each cell by .loc, and overwrite each cell with desired values.

However, even if we only have 1 group of 3 rows, this is still an apparently silly and tedious way.

My question is: can we possibly

1. find a general operation to rearrange cells by their relative position of in a group
2. repeat this operation over all groups?

Comment: Do you already have the Output position dataframe?

Comment: @anky Sadly no because the actual input has hundreds of cells, I can't manually adjust all of them

Comment: Sorry I dont follow, then what is the logic of the rearrangement? What is the fixed rule?

Comment: @anky ah sorry for being ambiguous! the rule is the transformation from example input group to output, exactly like that. I want to apply this to a dataframe of many such group. By 'no' I meant I dont have the output from the actual dataframe.

Comment: @anky they do have some other name. position is just to denote position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proposal which uses numpy indexing with reshaping on each group.

**Setup:**

Lets assume your original df and the position dataframes are as below:

```
d = {'group': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
 'value1': ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'F1'],
 'value2': ['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2', 'E2', 'F2'],
 'value3': ['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3', 'E3', 'F3']}
out_d = {'group': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
         'value1': ['position1', 'position4', 'position7',
                    'position1', 'position4', 'position7'], 
         'value2': ['position8', 'position2', 'position5',
                  'position8', 'position2', 'position5'], 
         'value3': ['position6', 'position9', 'position3', 
                    'position6', 'position9', 'position3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
out = pd.DataFrame(out_d)

print("Original dataframe :\n\n",df,"\n\n Position dataframe :\n\n",out)

Original dataframe :

   group value1 value2 value3
0      1     A1     A2     A3
1      1     B1     B2     B3
2      1     C1     C2     C3
3      2     D1     D2     D3
4      2     E1     E2     E3
5      2     F1     F2     F3 

 Position dataframe :

    group     value1     value2     value3
0      1  position1  position8  position6
1      1  position4  position2  position9
2      1  position7  position5  position3
3      2  position1  position8  position6
4      2  position4  position2  position9
5      2  position7  position5  position3
```

---

**Working Solution:**

**Method 1:** : Creating a function and use in `df.groupby.apply`

```
#remove letters and extract only position numbers and subtract 1 
#since python indexing starts at 0

o = out.applymap(lambda x: int(''.join(re.findall('\d+',x)))-1 if type(x)==str else x)

#Merge this output with original dataframe
df1 = df.merge(o,on='group',left_index=True,right_index=True,suffixes=('','_pos'))
# Build a function which rearranges the df based on the position df:
def fun(x):
    c = x.columns.str.contains("_pos")
    return pd.DataFrame(np.ravel(x.loc[:,~c])[np.ravel(x.loc[:,c])]
                        .reshape(x.loc[:,~c].shape),
                         columns=x.columns[~c])
```

---

```
output = (df1.groupby("group").apply(fun).reset_index("group")
          .reset_index(drop=True))
print(output)

   group value1 value2 value3
0      1     A1     C2     B3
1      1     B1     A2     C3
2      1     C1     B2     A3
3      2     D1     F2     E3
4      2     E1     D2     F3
5      2     F1     E2     D3
```

**Method 2:** Iterate through each group and re-arrange:

```
o = out.applymap(lambda x: int(''.join(re.findall('\d+',x)))-1 if type(x)==str else x)
df1 = df.merge(o,on='group',left_index=True,right_index=True,
               suffixes=('','_pos')).set_index("group")
idx = df1.index.unique()


l = []
for i in idx:
    v = df1.loc[i]
    c = v.columns.str.contains("_pos")
    l.append(np.ravel(v.loc[:,~c])[np.ravel(v.loc[:,c])].reshape(v.loc[:,~c].shape))
final = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(l),index=df1.index,
        columns=df1.columns[~c]).reset_index()

print(final)

   group value1 value2 value3
0      1     A1     C2     B3
1      1     B1     A2     C3
2      1     C1     B2     A3
3      2     D1     F2     E3
4      2     E1     D2     F3
5      2     F1     E2     D3
```

Comment: wow anky thanks so much!! let me take a look

Comment: @GrumpyCivet Sure, glad to help. Let me know how it went ,  It was an interesting problem though. :) I have added 2 solutions.

Comment: method1: everything worked but at step '''output = (df1.groupby("group").apply(fun).reset_index("group").reset_index(drop=True))''' there is an error "ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 9 into shape (3,4)"

Comment: method2 works perfectly! Im still figuring out how this works exactly though. Anyway many thanks anky!

Comment: @GrumpyCivet pleasure, wondering why the method1 didnt work. it works on my system. May be you have other columns in the position df which you may want to remove and retain only group, value1,value2,value3